# std:: accumulate division by zero

Tags: c++

I do not understand why I get a division by zero in the following code.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type avg_abs_difference(T first, T second)
{
    using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;
    if(first == second)return 0;
    Type oldValue = *first;
    Type count = 0;
    Type res = std::accumulate(std::next(first), second, 0, [&](Type a, Type b)
                           {
                            Type result = a + std::abs(b- oldValue);
                            oldValue = b;
                            ++count;
                            return  result; }
                            )/ count;
    return res ;
}
```

but when I pull the division outward like this, it does not occur.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type avg_abs_difference(T first, T second)
{
    using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;
    if(first == second)return 0;
    Type oldValue = *first;
    Type count = 0;
    Type res = std::accumulate(std::next(first), second, 0, [&](Type a, Type b)
                           {
                            Type result = a + std::abs(b- oldValue);
                            oldValue = b;
                            ++count;
                            return  result; }
                            );
    return res / count;
}
```

Comment: Regardless of this problem, the third argument for accumulate should be `Type{}`, not `0`. The return type matches this argument type. Or... just don't use `accumulate` here, it looks way too hacky.

Answer (score 14):

That's because "count" is evaluated before std::accumulate, so the side effect is not taken into consideration.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of
> evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions
> listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other
> subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the
> same expression is evaluated again.